# ResultPropertyCollection does not contain a definition for Item. C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, directoryservices

So I am rewriting a program from VB to C# and am running into some difficult using DirectoryServices. In VB the code looks something like

```
Dim myResultPropertyValueCollection As ResultPropertyValueCollection = myResultPropertyCollection.Item(FieldName)
```

how may I get the C# equivalent? In C# I am trying

```
ResultPropertyValueCollection resultPropertyValueCollection = resultPropertyCollection.Item(fieldName);
```

However i am getting an error stating that ResultPropertyCollection does not contain a definition for Item.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found it.

```
ResultPropertyValueCollection resultPropertyValueCollection = resultPropertyCollection[fieldName];
```